# Replace setuptools.errors with distutils.errors?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

When we use this import in setup.py:

```
from setuptools import errors
```

we get this error when running:

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
$ . .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install --upgrade -e '.\[dev\]\`
[...]
running ImportError: cannot import name 'errors' from 'setuptools'
```

This can be worked around with by running

```
$ pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

as the initial step. But to avoid requiring everyone to do that extra step, we are considering replacing setuptools.errors with distutils.errors - see https://github.com/meeshkan/py-http-types/pull/35/commits/9472d23138f5e077868e73deaf7168a5da83cb84 for the context.

Is this recommended, or is there a better way? What about the "direct usage of distutils is now actively discouraged" warning at https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#distutils?

Comment: The warning refers rather to the usage of `distutils.core.setup`. If you don't use the `RemovedCommandError`, import `distutils.errors` safely, [it's not going anywhere](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.errors).